# Фильтры объектов в OpenLayers при получении из источника (через GeoJSON)

Tags: openlayers, ajax, javascript, http, geojson

Мне приходит такого вида **GeoJSON**:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-108.04,44.68]},"properties":{"course":184.7,"vid":1}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-111.04,45.68]},"properties":{"course":44.1,"vid":2}}]}
```

Получает его **OpenLayers** сам:

```
vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
   "Simple Geometry",
   {
      protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
        url: "http://localhost:8885/view",
        filterToParams: function(filter, params) {
          if (filter.type === OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.BBOX) {
            params.bbox = filter.value.toArray();
            if (filter.projection) {
              params.bbox.push(filter.projection.getCode());
            }
          }
          return params;
        }
      }),
      strategies: [
        new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({force: true, interval:10000}),
        new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({resFactor:2})
      ],
      styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        "default": myStyle
      })
   }
);
```

Код основан на примере [Script Protocol](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/cross-origin.html) (см. [скрипт](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/cross-origin.js) из этого примера).
Как я понимаю тут определен некий фильтр для отсева лишних данных от сервера (если сервер этого не сделал), и дальше не используются фильтры в **Rule** уже не нужны для скрытия лишних объектов.
Это все правильно, и ускоряет работы с картой на малых масштабах (когда виден маленький кусочек карты).

На данный момент я делаю фильтрацию через контекст стилей:

```
var myContext = {
    getDisplay : function (f) {
        return featureIndexOf(f.attributes.vid) 
            ? "" 
            : "none";
    },
    getOpacity : function (f) {
        if ( featureIndexOf(f.attributes.vid) ) {
            return compareJsonDateNow(f.attributes.time) 
                ? 0.8 
                : 0.5;
        }
        return 1.0;
    }
}

var myStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
    externalGraphic: "${getGraphic}",
    graphicWidth: 16,
    graphicHeight: 16,
    graphicOpacity: "${getOpacity}",
    display: "${getDisplay}"
},{
    context: myContext
});
```

Мне бы хотелось как-то дополнить этот фильтр (или переписать его), что бы он уже на этом этапе фильтровал объекты которые попадают в слой. Что бы не приходилось скрывать лишние через фильтры **Rule**, которые заметно замедляют работу на больших масштабах (например когда видна вся карта) с большим числом числом объектов.

Отфильтровать хотелось бы по равенству некоего атрибута (из *properties*), т.е. если свойство объекта равно тому-то, то он попадает на слой, а в ином случае мы про него забываем (удаляем, по сути, из принятых из источника данных).

*Вопрос: как это сделать, если возможно?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [OpenLayers.​Filter](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Filter-js.html) и не мало удивитесь...

Comment: Это не совсем то что нужно, но уже что-то...  
Спасибо!